# Wordpress MySQL Query for category pages

Tags: mysql, wordpress, categories

I am using this query on my wordpress index.php to display posts and sort them by date (oldest first ASC). I use this database query because query_posts didn't work for me for some reason.

http://pastebin.com/e7vVyKP9

Now I want to use the exact same query on my category pages. I somehow have to add some lines in order to only show posts of the category which is active.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: you do not need to use `$wpdb` use `wp_query` instead of `query_posts`

Comment: @DavidChase Thanks, can you give me an example of how to use wp_query for my scenario? I want to show all posts (publish & future) of the active category and sort them by date ascending. Thanks in advance!

Comment: of all active categories? can you be more specific? you want all posts within a category ?

Comment: sorry. I just want a normal category template. So basically what I want is normal category archives but in ascending order (and showing also future posts).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so based on your information that you posted you could use something like this:

```
$args = array( 'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ), 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
        $the_query->the_post();
        the_time('l, F jS, Y');
        the_content();
        the_category();
endwhile;


wp_reset_postdata();
```

### UPDATED WITH REQUEST

```
get_header(); ?>

    <section id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
            <header class="archive-header">
                <h1 class="archive-title"><?php printf( __( 'Category Archives: %s' ), '<span>' . single_cat_title( '', false ) . '</span>' ); ?></h1>

            <?php if ( category_description() ) : // Show an optional category description ?>
                <div class="archive-meta"><?php echo category_description(); ?></div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </header><!-- .archive-header -->

            <?php
            $args = array( 'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'future' ), 'post_type' => 'post','orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'ASC' );

            $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );


            while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    the_time('l, F jS, Y');
                    the_content();
                    the_category();
            endwhile;


            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>

        <?php else : ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </section><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is a twentytweleve category page that displays:
[**this page**](http://davidchase.koding.com/kodingwp/?cat=1)

Comment: yeah the `while` to `endwhile` is the loop where you can get all the stuff you need for the archive/category page such `the_category()`, etc

Comment: unfortunately:  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endwhile' (T_ENDWHILE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\spun\archive.php on line 96

Comment: you dont need `<?php endwhile; else: ?>` that `endwhile` because you dont have a open while check your pastebin, nor the `else` unless you have an open `if`

Comment: okay, please check again: http://pastebin.com/TDLSRMfy
now it works, but it only shows 1 post. it seems as if the loop doesn't start again but ends after displaying one post.

Comment: can you show me your entire template/page where you are using my code

Comment: you mean the complete archive.php? sure: http://pastebin.com/BtWxtLHt
it's a bit messy but the way the posts are displayed is working perfectly. as I said: only problem right now is that there is only 1 post displayed.

Comment: thats because you stuff like `get_the_category` and `the_date` inside the loop

Comment: according to the pastebin.com/BtWxtLHt you dont have anything inside the loop that i gave you.. look at my answer and compare it to your pastebin

Comment: odd? did you try to the `get_the_category` inside the loop the loop starts with `while` and ends with `endwhile;`

Comment: i tested my answer on my local wordpress and it works i got all my posts as dictated by the loop.

Comment: can you please paste me you're local version so I can check what I'm doing wrong? I mean the whole .php file. Of course you can erase the part where the posts are displayed.

Comment: is page your archives.php(template) or archive.php? just want to make sure

Comment: sorry? I don't get your question. The category pages of my theme work with the archives.php - there is no category.php in the theme.

Comment: Meaning there are two php files that come with wordpress either in the theme or default one called archives.php which is a template to use in the pages section and the other being archive.php which is where the loop is housed for getting archived data

Comment: ... I acutally don't know right now and I can only look into my files this evening at home. can you tell from what I copied into pastebin? that was the whole file.

Comment: ah I checked it out. the file is called archive.php

Comment: heres an online testing location for me [**here**](http://davidchase.koding.com/kodingwp/?m=201303) im using my answer to display monthly archives is this what you are trying to get. my answer is located inside archive.php

Comment: okay, can you pastebin me your archive.php ? Then I can compare it to my file and see what might cause the error for me.

Comment: I see that you're link is a monthly archive and not a category page. what I am trying to get is a normal category page (showing all posts from the category the user is in.)

Comment: then you need a to edit the category page... like i have here http://davidchase.koding.com/kodingwp/?cat=2

Comment: can you please post me your code for that .php file? otherwise I can't figure out what I have done wrong.

Comment: updated answer with category.php page that i linked to last comment

Comment: `while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
                    $the_query->the_post();
                    the_time('l, F jS, Y');
                    the_content();
                    the_category();
            endwhile;`

Is this where I can edit how the posts should be printed out? Because I neither want the_time nor the_content nor the_category to be acutally displayed.

Comment: correct, thats the loop which will get more posts for you instead of one.

Comment: I am a beginner to PHP so can you tell me whether I can also add HTML-code in this loop? so basically something like this?
`while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
<div>test test blabla</div>;
endwhile;`

How can I add a bigger HTML block into this loop to tell the query HOW to display which values where?

Comment: you can put html inside the loop like so `echo '<div>' . wpautop(get_the_content()) . '</div>';`

Comment: please refer to this for more info https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: that means all the html and plain text has to be in ' ' and only PHP is allowed to be outside the ' ' ?